# Recover password of ZIP archive, having its decrypted and extracted content

Tags: encryption, aes, zip

Can I recover a password of an AES-encrypted ZIP if I know its extracted & decrypted content? The archive contains two files protected with two different passwords.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly, but maybe not in the way you think. AES encryption is resistant to known-plaintext attacks (i.e. where you can recover the key just by having both the unencrypted and encrypted data). This is assuming there are no other weaknesses or side channel attacks present in the implementation used for ZIP encryption.

Your only option is to try every possible password on the encrypted ZIP (which will take a long time), and you will know the key is correct when the decrypted result matches your existing decrypted copy. This is slightly better than not knowing what the unencrypted data looks like, but doesn't let you cheat AES. For more details, see these answers:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1515
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11716590